# Binidng null values with Combobox using Winforms

Tags: c#

I have this List to get data from a database (MYSQL) using `dapper`.

```
    public List<ComplaintActionsModel> GetComplaintActions(int complaintID)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
        {
            var output = conn.Query<ComplaintActionsModel>($@"
                SELECT
                    Status
                FROM customercomplaintsactions WHERE id = {complaintID}").ToList();
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Then on user click I load the values into the Combo-box. Like so:

```
List<ComplaintActionsModel> complaintsActionsList = new List<ComplaintActionsModel>();
private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = (int)ComplaintsData.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value; // Get id of selected row in DataGrid

    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();

    complaintsActionsList = db.GetComplaintActions(id); // Find Status from database

    status.DataBindings.Add("Text", complaintsActionsList, "Status", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged); // Set value of status combobox from the database
}

// Model
public class ComplaintActionsModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Question**

As an example:

If MySQL data shows a value of 'Open for Investigation', it'll then select this index:

[image]

Next, if I go to the next record, and click the button - it should show an empty value in combobox - because there is a `null` value.

How can I unselect an item in my combobox if the value returned is `null`?

Comment: just add in the option when obtaining the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this should get you headed in a good direction. First, handle the Binding.Format event, like so:

```
Binding b = new Binding("Text", complaintsActionsList, "Status", true);
b.Format += complaintAction_Format;
DataBindings.Add(b);
```

Then, do whatever you want to do when the value is null inside the format event, like so:

```
private void complaintAction_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    //do whatever you want to do in case of null
    e.Value = e.Value == null ? "" : e.Value;
    //or
    if(e.Value == null)
    {
        myComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited to add setting a combobox selectedindex to -1, which I "think" is what you intend to do...?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check my code tomorrow morning and get back you asap.

Comment: How can this be modified to do multiple data-binding? I have more than 10 fields not just the 1 `Status`.

Comment: Just repeat those three lines for each field. You can use a different handler, like "complaintDate_Format" and "complaintNotes_Format" to do other fields. You need to create a new Binding for each one.

Comment: I see.. I'll accept the answer as you have given me a valid answer. :D